# How do I fill in missing dates as rows and give other values? (exceptional case)

Tags: sql-server, database, join

I have a lot of explaining to do for the context of this question so bear with me.

At my company, we have a SQL Server database and I'm working in the Management studio 2014.
We have a table that's called Jobstatistics, which displays how many Jobs are done during Intervals of one hour each. 
[The table looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9sy59.png)

The station field is basically different areas jobs can be done at.

As you can see, some rows are missing for certain intervals and this is because of the way this table gets filled with data. To fill this table we have a script running that looks at another table and aggregates the amount of jobs for all dates between this interval. In other words, if there aren't any jobs, there won't be a row inserted because there will be nothing to insert (no rows from the other table to aggregate any jobs on).

What I want to do here is fill in these extra intervals with 0 as the amount of Jobs. So there will always be the 24 intervals (hours) for each day and for each station. On top of that we have set targets which we would like to achieve and I declared these in another table, called JobstatisticsTargets, which you could call a calendar table to join the Jobstatistics table on.

[The calender table looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N7kTE.png)

I have tried doing a left or right join so the missing intervals would get filled in and the Jobs would at least get NULL values, but the join clause doesn't do what I expect it to.

This is my tried attempt

> ```
> SELECT a.[Station], a.[Interval], a.[Jobs], b.[28JPH], b.[35JPH]
> FROM [JobStatistics] a
> RIGHT JOIN [JobStatisticsTargets] b
>   ON CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),a.Interval,108) = b.Interval
> WHERE DATEDIFF(DAY, a.Interval, GETDATE()) < 12
>   AND Station LIKE '138010'
> ORDER BY a.Station, a.Interval
> ```

The LEFT JOIN does exactly the same as I would expect a normal join to do and it doesn't append any intervals with NULL values. (the query is just for one station and a few days so I could test easily)

Any help is much appreciated. I will check this topic regularly so be sure to ask any questions regarding the context if you have any and I will try to explain it as good as I can!

**EDIT**
With some help the query now looks like this

> ```
> SELECT a.[Station], b.[Interval], a.[Jobs], b.[28JPH], b.[35JPH]
> FROM [JobStatistics] a
> RIGHT JOIN [JobStatisticsTargets] b
>   ON CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),a.Interval,108) = b.Interval
>     AND CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),a.Interval,110) = CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),GETDATE(),110)
>     AND Station LIKE '138010'
> ORDER BY b.Interval
> ```

I filter on today's date now because otherwise the extra rows aren't what I want them to be at all. The problem is that I don't know an easy way of filling in my stations. I suppose I need a subquery for those or is there another way?

The problem now as well is that I can't do this query for different stations. I would expect 24 rows for each station representing all the intervals, but I get this as a result:

> ```
> Station   Interval    Jobs    28JPH   35JPH
> NULL      00:30:00    NULL    0       0
> NULL      01:30:00    NULL    0       0
> NULL      02:30:00    NULL    0       0
> NULL      03:30:00    NULL    0       0
> 134040    04:30:00    2       0       0
> 136060    04:30:00    2       0       0
> 131080    04:30:00    2       0       0
> 138010    05:30:00    2       0       0
> NULL      06:30:00    NULL    0       0
> NULL      07:30:00    NULL    28      35
> NULL      08:30:00    NULL    28      35
> ...
> ```

Comment: You need to use a right join because the missing values are on the left table.

Comment: I tried that and this doesn't change the output whatsoever. That's why I am a little confused. The join isn't doing what I expect it would.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You filter on a field from the table which rows may not be presented in the join result: >>>AND Station LIKE '138010'
You should change your query and put this condition in ON CLAUSE, not in WHERE

Comment: I do get an output, but just as if it were a normal JOIN clause (only the rows that are in the left table with corresponding targets).
I've tried putting the condition in the on clause and the output still stays the same.

Comment: There is anothe condition, DATEDIFF(DAY, a.Interval, GETDATE()) < 12, that turns your outer join into inner.This one must also migrate into ON CLAUSE

Comment: I see, thanks a lot for the answer. I feel this is certainly a step in the right direction.
However, how am I able to fill in the NULL values like this?
I should at least be able to fill in the interval values, otherwise I will have to do this query exclusively for each day and fill it in with the intervals from the right table.

Answer (score 0):

check this script and let me know,

```
declare @t table(interval datetime,jobs int)
insert into @t VALUES('2017-04-28 05:30',1),('2017-04-28 06:30',5),('2017-04-29 06:30',5)
--select * from @t
;With CTE as
(
  select cast('00:00' as time) as IntervalTime
  union ALL
  select DATEADD(MINUTE,30,IntervalTime)
  from cte
  where IntervalTime<'23:30'
)
,CTE1 AS(
select interval,jobs
,dense_rank()over( order by cast(interval as date))rn
from @t
)
select * FROM
(
select distinct  case when t.interval is null then 
 DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, 
 (select top 1 interval from cte1 where rn=n.number)), cast(c.IntervalTime as datetime))
 else t.interval end Newinterval,isnull(t.jobs,0) Jobs

from CTE c
left join  cte1 t
on  c.IntervalTime=cast(t.interval as time)
cross apply(select  number from master.dbo.spt_values
     where name is null and number<=(select max(rn) from cte1))n
)t4
where Newinterval is not null
```